# Sending data between client with ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, push

Please help me think of solution here.

I'm transforming lotus note application to ASP.NET.

In lotus note, we can pass the application(data) from staff to his/her manager for approval.
The staff can also check status of his/her data whether the manager is opening it, approved it or not.

This process can be done in real time. I mean on the staff screen he/she will see status is changing from data sent --> manager is opening --> manager accepted or manager rejected it.

In the same time, if other staffs try to track this application(data) they will see the same screen with the first staff.

Now, in asp.net, i'm thinking of sending data from staff to manager directly. I don't want manager's web browser need to do polling for every xx millisecond. I'm not quite too sure it can be done or not in asp.net because i'm not the WEB guy.

After doing a research for a while, i found that comet may help me on that but it seems pretty hard. And I don't know it is suitable for my problem or not or someone may guide me a better idea on this.

In short, Which solution i should use with this problem to achieve my goal?

Sorry for my English

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing Realtime-Communication via XMPP. There is a project called [jabber.net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) with which you can create custom jabberclients in the background. It's pretty easy to implement, reliable and fast. In my case the user doesn't even know that he's actually chatting in the background. As the Information are shown in standard web-controls. Messages are created automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but my company ask us to develop on our own. I don't think we can use external .dll in our project.